# How to compare and register array values which are replicated

Tags: c

I am having trouble interpreting the logic of this exercise...

The exercise asks me to register 5 "brands" in a structure 
and the output must show how many times each brand repeated, if it has been registered more than once of course.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define C 5

typedef struct      
{
    int id;
    char brands[30];
} Something;


Something a[C];
int main() 
{
    int i=0, j=0;

    //input
    for(i=0;i<C;i++)
    {
        a[i].id = i;

        printf("BRAND: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(a[i].brands);
    }

    for(i=0;i<C;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<C;j++)
        {
            if (strcmp(a[i].brands, a[j].brands)==0)
                // 
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The brand inputs values are not constant, it could be anything.
So I was thinking to look through a search, comparing whether there is equal brand and incrementing a counter for each. (This counter is where I stuck, since I dont know how many different brands will be in the registry)...

**E.g. 1**
Inputs

```
Ford
Ferrari
Ford
Nissan
Nissan
```

Output should be like this:

```
Ford 2x
Ferrari 1x
Nissan 2x
```

**E.g. 2**
Inputs

```
Ford
Ford
Ford
Ford
Nissan
```

Output:

```
Ford 4x
Nissan 1x
```

Comment: Please be more specific. What exactly don't you understand? Would it help to suggest that you put a counter inside your struct? Then for each input, search the `Something` list. If the input already exists then increment the counter. Otherwise fill in a new struct for that input (with its count set to 1).

Comment: Search for the difference between a Set and a Bag in C. Using a Bag, it should be easy to both output the number of references and to manage multiple registrations with less memory.

Comment: "The brand inputs are not constant". What do you mean "not constant"? Do you mean the *number of inputs* is not constant? If so, then there are two general approaches: 1. Use dynamic memory allocations. 2. Use a static MAX value for allocating the data structure memory. Obviously the former is much better in general.

Comment: @kaylum Ty, ill consider creating 2 structs (one for general and other for brands with a counter inside it). I was wondering if its possible to process this information through a search...

Comment: "The exercise asks me to register 5 "brands" in a structure" and then "I dont know how many different brands will be in the registry". Those two statements seem to be contradictory. Can you please clarify? It can  make a big difference to what might be the best approach.

Comment: I mean I can register 5 equal brands in the same way I could register 5 different from each other. I changed the example to be clearer.

Comment: Never use `gets`, since there is no way to prevent buffer overflow.  The man page even says not to use it.  Instead, use `fgets`, which takes a buffer size argument.

Comment: Before creating a new entry, you should look to see if the brand has already been registered.  If it has, then increment a counter in the brand structure, and don't create a new entry.  If it has not, then create a new entry and initialize the counter to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve what you want. Below are some pointers that will hopefully help you reach a solution.

The first step would be to include a counter in your structure.

```
typedef struct      
{
    int id;
    char brands[30];
    unsigned int count;
} Something;
```

Initialise all the `count` fields to 0. The `brands` field only contains a valid string if the `count` is greater than 0. Since `a` is a global variable, all the fields are automatically initialised to 0 so there is no extra code needed.

Then each time you read an input the code would search through `a` from the beginning. The search logic would be

```
for each 'a' entry
    if (count field > 0)
        if (brand field is same as input)
            // Found a match
            increment count field
            break out of loop
        // else will check next entry by continuing the loop
    else
        // Reached end of valid entries. Hence no match.
        Create a new entry. Copy input into the brand field. 
        Set count field to 1.
        break out of loop
```

I have deliberately shown pseudo code to leave the C code as an exercise for you. But basically the idea is (as stated in my earlier comment) to search the existing valid entries after reading each input (you don't need two seperate arrays).